# CSS : how to make entire LI box click able for pagination box

Tags: html, css

How to make entire `LI` box clickable for pagination box, the html and css part are working fine.  I was able to click the link with its page number to go to second page.

Problem is: when you click the `li` box, the blank part beside the number, it not able to link to other page. I would like that to clickable.

What should I do?

```css
.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pagination li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font: 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.pagination li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(89, 141, 235);
}

.pagination li.first {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.pagination li.last {
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.pagination li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
}

.pagination li.current {
  background: #89B3CC;
  border: 1px solid #89B3CC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1" title="First">«</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=-1" title="Previous">&lt;</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">2</li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=4">4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=5">&gt;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=5" title="Last">»</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfw0p525/)

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because padding is part of the parent element and not the `a` tag. You could try substituting `li` padding with an `a` margin or run a javascript onclick event to take care of page redirection. **Upd**: could you please fix your JSFiddle link?

Comment: fiddle link fixed, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can update this part:**

```
.pagination li {
      display: inline-block;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-right: -1px;
      font: 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: #FFFFFF;
    }

    .pagination li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: rgb(89, 141, 235);
      display:block;
      padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
    }
```

**MARKUP PART**

```
 <li class="active"><a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1">2</a></li>
```

```css
.pagination {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pagination li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font: 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.pagination li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(89, 141, 235);
  display:block;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
}

.pagination li.first {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.pagination li.last {
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.pagination li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
}

.pagination li.current {
  background: #89B3CC;
  border: 1px solid #89B3CC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="first">
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1" title="First">«</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=-1" title="Previous">&lt;</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1">2</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=4">4</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=5">&gt;</a>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=5" title="Last">»</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

move the padding to the anchor styling, you can set width and height also to have the boxes bigger.

```
.pagination {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }


.pagination li {
  display: inline;

  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-right: -1px;
  font: 13px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.pagination li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 6px 10px 6px 10px;
  color: rgb(89, 141, 235);
}

.pagination li.first {
  border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.pagination li.last {
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.pagination li:hover {
  background: #EEE;
}

.pagination li.current {
  background: #89B3CC;
  border: 1px solid #89B3CC;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this

```
<a href="/fs/mapping/mapping.php?page=1" title="First">
  <li class="first">
    «
  </li>
</a>
```

and change style selector from `.pagination li a` to `.pagination a`.

Another way is to get rid of `<ul>` and `<li>` and use `<span>` instead. `<span>` inside of `<a>` looks more natural than `<li>` inside of `<a>`